# Globally changing width of scroll bars in my application

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF application that runs on a touch screen computer.  I'd like to change all of the scroll bars in the app to be much wider.  Is there a way to do that globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo have to `override the default template of scrollViewer` to increase the width of vertical scrollbar. To apply the template across all your scrollbars put the override style in your App resources -

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>

          <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
            Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
            Width="40"
            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
          <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can set width of `'PART_VerticalScrollBar'` to your desired width (say 40 as in example above).Placing this style under `Application Resources` (App.xaml) makes it applied across complete application.

Comment: Thanks.  This works but it's showing the scroll bars on the left hand of the screen.  Any idea how to get around that?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Set `HorizontalContentAlignment to Left` and `VerticalContentAlignment to Top` in style. See if it works.

Comment: Also for default template refer to this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278065(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: The first suggestion didn't work but I took the entire default template and changed the width and it's just what I needed.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `Style` inside of the Resources indicating the `TargetType`.

This style will be applied to all ScrollBars in your xaml file.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        ....
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I applied Kent's answer from this post-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321247/how-to-increase-scrollbar-width-in-wpf-scrollviewer but put it in a resource dictionary.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">10</sys:Double>
  <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}">10</sys:Double>
//a bunch of styles
</ResourceDictionary>
```