# How to increase size of all Scrollbars (application-wide)?

Tags: wpf, scrollbar

I want to change the width/height of the scrollbars (including the ones inside the datagrids and other controls) in all the application.
I successfully tested and tweacked this solution which applies to ONE datagrid:

[How to increase size of Datagrid Scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904062/how-to-increase-size-of-datagrid-scrollbar)

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>                   
    </Style> 
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

But, how can I change the style of ALL the scrollbars and do it "application-wide"?

I suppose I should do it from `Application.Resources` but did'nt find any solution for that.

**EDIT:**
Adding the scrollbar style in `<Application.Resources>` does not fully work as it does not changes the scrollbars inside other controls (like datagrids).

Comment: Place you style in application wide resource dictionary

Comment: I.e. in `<Application.Resources>` in App.xaml.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I tried, but I don't know how to define `<DataGrid.Resources>` inside `<Application.Resources>`.

Comment: Yo don't need to use `DataGrid.Resources`, use `<Application.Resources>` instead, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/fundamentals/xaml-resources-define) is an example

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, see my edit. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamCalvetBohl Which Windows version are you using? A global ScrollBar Style works fine for me (for e.g DataGrid and ListView) on Windows 10.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476305/wpf-some-styles-not-applied-on-datatemplate-controls).

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Tanks, but the solution works, but only for Scrollviewer control. DataGrid is not affected.

Comment: @Clemens, I use Windows 10. I used the code I posted in a global style (in `<Application.Resources>`) but it only works specifically for `ScrollBar`control.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. The question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970212/globally-changing-width-of-scroll-bars-in-my-application does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what you require it seems that you need to change the styling of some `ScrollBar`s only. And for this you need to somehow appoint which scrollbars to change ("all of them") and which not ("except DataGrids").

I'd do the following:

- in your App.xaml (as already pointed out) define the style you want to apply to the scrollbars, however make it a named style with `x:Key="..."` element:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyScrollBarStyle" TargetType="ScrollBar">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>                   
    </Style> 
</Application.Resources>
```

Now each time you want to draw a scrollbar with this style, simply add `Style="{StaticResource MyScrollBarStyle}"` to the scrollbar tag.

Comment: Thanks, but I REALLY want to apply the style to ALL scrollbars. And, as I told, this does not change the style of scrollbars inside other controls.

Comment: I've found this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad8548f9-7ad2-4980-acb3-17c0088f4038/create-a-style-trigger-for-quotparent-of-a-given-type-existsquot?forum=wpf discussing something similar to what you need. Unfortunately, there aren't enough details given there  so I can verify this solution on a short notice.

Comment: Damn, I've read your question again and it occurred to me that you want the opposite of what I was proposing. Nevertheless, I've checked and the App.xaml solution changes the size of ALL scrollbars, hence there must be something in your code that styles the scrollbars of panels separately. Search your code for PART_VerticalScrollBar and PART_HorizontalScrollBar and make sure those are not taking precedence over your code. I'm sorry for my previous answer, it was totally not applicable.