# How to change the size of a Datagrid Scrollbar?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, scrollbar

I have a Datagrid that displays the  data on Runtime, and as it has lot of data it itself brings scrollbar on it, but the size is smaller. Can anyone tell how to change size of scrollbar and make it bigger ?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgUnitVerReefer" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SelectionMode="Single"      SelectionUnit="FullRow" Margin="20,94,26,0" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"     Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="334"      HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFA4C4EA" FontFamily="Microsoft New Tai Lue" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFA4C4EA" MouseDoubleClick="DgUnitVerReefer_MouseDoubleClick" FontSize="16" Width="387">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding Path= UNIT_NUMBER}" Width="350" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and then on window_loaded in load data and assign to datagrid.

```
   DgUnitVerReefer.DataContext = objVerifyUnit.DtLovReefer.DefaultView;
   DgUnitVerReefer.ItemsSource = objVerifyUnit.DtLovReefer.DefaultView;
   DgUnitVerReefer.DisplayMemberPath = "UNIT_NUMBER";
   DgUnitVerReefer.SelectedValuePath = "UNI_ID";
```

on running it display scrollbar with smaller size, how to change its size ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can apply style for the `ScrollBar` type at the `DataGrid` level. We should use a `Trigger` against the `Orientation` property to apply style to the vertical scrollbar only:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>                   
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

For horizontal scrollbar, we need to set the `Height` instead, and the `Value` for the trigger is `Horizontal`.

Comment: Was taking me quite a while to figure out how to apply a style to only the vertical Scrollbar. What an obvious, simple answer. Just wanted to thank you as well!

Answer (score 4):

[King King solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24904667/361177) doesn't work if you want to [reduce the width of the `ScrollBar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614109). In this case you also should set the `MinWidth` property.

An other solution based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321247) is to modify the [SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.verticalscrollbarwidth) property:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <system:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">5</system:Double>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```