# Change ScrollBar width in ScrollViewer programatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, scrollviewer

When I create a new ScrollViewer, I need to modify the size of the ScrollBars in the ScrollViewer (change the VerticalScroll width and the HorizontalScroll height), **programatically**.

I tried the following based in a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321247/how-to-increase-scrollbar-width-in-wpf-scrollviewer) found in SO, without success:

```
    public static ScrollViewer CreateScrollViewer()
    {
        ScrollViewer result = new ScrollViewer();
        // I need to set the scroll width and height here
        // I tried the following with no success
        result.Resources.Add(SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth, 100);
        return result;
    }
```

I saw [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321247/how-to-increase-scrollbar-width-in-wpf-scrollviewer) solutions [to](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7096b432-ae09-4fb5-acfd-20813086c11c/changing-width-of-scrollbar-inside-scrollviewer?forum=wpf) change [them](https://michlg.wordpress.com/2010/05/15/wpf-how-to-change-the-width-of-a-scrollbar-scrollviewer/), but all are XAML based. I **need to do it in runtime, in pure C#**. How could I do this?

Comment: Have you considered using a `Style` instead?

Comment: @MikeEason: Yes, I considered it, but my requirements are pure C#, no XAML.

Comment: Where does this requirement come from?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: From my company. We're trying to avoid XAML because in our team we use a semanticmerge tool that supports C# but doesn't support XAML.

Comment: @DanielPeñalba: That is a pretty strange decision, to say the least.

Comment: What is `VScroll` width and the `HScroll` height? Isn't that from WindowsForms? Do you just mean that you want to alter the size of the `ScrollBar`s?

Comment: @Sheridan: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `ScrollBar`s from the `ScrollViewer`'s `ControlTemplate`. You can find out how to do that from the [How to: Find ControlTemplate-Generated Elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN and you can find details of the default `ControlTemplate` in the [ScrollViewer Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970847%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, but in short, try this:

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
scrollViewer.ApplyTemplate();
ScrollBar scrollBar = 
    (ScrollBar)scrollViewer.Template.FindName("PART_VerticalScrollBar", scrollViewer);
```

You can do the same for the horizontal `ScrollBar` which is named `PART_HorizontalScrollBar`.