# How to set ScrollViewer Bar Margin or Height?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scrollviewer

I need the scroll bar's height short than scrollview's height. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Your question is not really clear, maybe you should show us your code and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollBar template reaches out for system parameters to determine its width/height (depending on orientation). Therefore, you can override those parameters:

```
<Application
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
>
<Application.Resources>
    <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">50</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}">50</sys:Double>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Please Refer to this link for more information [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321247/how-to-increase-scrollbar-width-in-wpf-scrollviewer)