# WPF - Set width of web browser's scroll bar

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm trying to change the width of the scroll bar of a `WebBrowser` control.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321275/975959) answer to change its `ScrollViewer` like this:

```
<WebBrowser Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Column="0" Height="1993" Margin="3,3,0,3">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer.Resources>
            <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">100</sys:Double>
        </ScrollViewer.Resources>
    </ScrollViewer>
</WebBrowser>
```

But I'm getting `The type 'WebBrowser' does not support direct content` error.

I know that the `WebBrowser` of `WPF` is just a wrapper around `WinForm's` so I'm guessing this is why I'm getting this error.

I don't want to use external components such as `CefSharp` or other browsers.

Is it possible using the native `WebBrowser`?

Thanks

Comment: Which scrollbars do you want to customize? The scrollbars of the page belong to the page and the only way to change them is using CSS.

Comment: I'm using the browser to show a PDF using adobe reader, but the scroll bar are of the web browser

Answer (score 0):

The WPF `WebBrowser` control actually wraps the native WebBrowser ActiveX control inside it. That doesn't really change the answer but it's good to know.

As Reza Aghaei already commented, the scrollbars are not WPF controls and cannot be modified like other scrollbars in WPF applications. However, I don't think that you can change the width of the IE scrollbars using CSS, because the styling is only limited to coloring:

```
scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #C0C0C0;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #C0C0C0;
/* etc */
```

Two possibilities come to mind. Either you use one of the jQuery scrollbar libraries that let you customize the scrollbar, or you use the native WPF `ScrollBar` instead.

Using jQuery scrollbars would force you to inject javascript on each page the user visits and it might get really dirty when the website already has custom jQuery scrollbars in use. This could be worth looking into, but I doubt it would work well enough in practice.

**Here's what I would try**

1. Hide the scrollbar by giving `overflow:hidden` style to the body of each page. You could also host the Windows Forms `WebBrowser` inside the `WindowsFormsHost` control so you would get access to the `ScrollBarsEnabled` property (which unfortunately isn't available on the WPF control).
2. Add the WPF `ScrollBar` next to your `WebBrowser` control and style it the way you want to. This could actually be a `UserControl` to ensure future reusability.
3. Set the WPF `ScrollBar`'s maximum value to the ScrollHeight of the HTML page.
4. Subscribe to the scroll event of WPF `ScrollBar`. Send the scroll events to the HTML page. You would also need to do it the other way to keep the WPF `ScrollBar` synced with scroll that happens using touch, mouse wheel or keyboard buttons.

I'm not on a computer right now so can't help with the numbers 3 and 4 but it should certainly be possible. Again you could run into pages that use some custom scrolling (jQuery) but hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. I'll look into it tomorrow. I don't now if it will work though since I won't be showing any HTML. It's used only as a PDF viewer using Acrobat Reader