# Change the width of the scrollbars in a scrollviewer on MousOver

Tags: wpf

I try to style a ScrollViewer so that the width of the ScrollBar element is changed on a MouseOver. I can style the ScrollViewer and give it an initial width, and it is also possible to change properties on a MouseOver, like the Opacity or Visibility. But I can't change the Width, that property is not changed.

I use this code as an example:

```
<Style x:Key="myScrollBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                <ScrollBar
                    Style="{StaticResource myScrollBarStyle}"
                    Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                    Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                    ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                <ScrollBar 
                    Style="{StaticResource myScrollBarStyle}"
                    Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                    Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                    ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Opacity is changed on a MouseOver but if I add a Width, it is ignored. If I look at ControlTemplate.Triggers then I can change the width on MouseOver but that is the width of the complete ScrollViewer, not the ScrollBar element. Even if I point to the element with the targetname PART_VerticalScrollBar.

Searching the internet only results in solutions to change the visibility or opacity, not the width. I could not find any solution.

Is there a solution to do this in a style?

Comment: Check the accepted answer of this question. It may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321247/how-to-increase-scrollbar-width-in-wpf-scrollviewer

Comment: That is to set the initial width. I need to change it in a MouseOver event.

Comment: I copied your XAML into a new project and added the following setter to the first trigger:

`<Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>`

It worked just fine.

If you're saying that doesn't work, then there is either some difference between your actual XAML and what you put in your question, or there is something else in your project (some other style or code) that is interfering with the trigger.

Comment: It is weird! If I add this to a new Window, then it works! I'll have a look further to other styles.

Comment: Ok, I found out it was caused by not setting the minwidth and the maxwidth. If I set these to 4 and 16 (which I want to be min and max state), then it works! Thanks!